# How to fetch data in .NET Core WEP API project from MS SQL, using existing SQL queries?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a `.NET Core 3.1 Web API` project and I have an existing `MS SQL` database filled with data.
In my project I need to fetch the data from the database and to return it as results via the API endpoints. I already have the `SQL` queries for fetching the data in the format:

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM <table>
WHERE <condition>
```

And I wonder, what is the best way to get to fetch the data from the database and in the same time to be able to maximum reuse the `SQL` code that I already have.

I was considering options like:

- using `Entity Framework Core` as a framework (but then, I already have the `SQL` code and I feel that using the entities with `LINQ` queries will only result with repetitive work, as I will have to translate my `SQL` queries into the `LINQ` queries);
- using `StoredProcedures` and somehow call them (so that I can copy paste my `SQL` code inside of the procedures and on that way to maximum reuse them). Still I am not sure what is the best way to call / write stored procedures, do I need to use any framework;
- using some combined approach, where I will actually use the `StoredProcedures` but I will call them via  `Entity Framework Core`;

The above points were some conclusions based on my research, as I am not experiences with `.NET Core` development in general. So any advices will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having a look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). It's a Micro-ORM that easily enables you to query your database with SQL, and then mapping the result to .NET objects.